# jquery bind paste and detect all input have value

Tags: jquery

```
$('#name, #password').bind('paste', function(){
    if($('#name').val().length !== 0){
        $('#submit').attr('disabled',false);
        $('#submit').css({opacity:1});
    }
    else{
        $('#submit').attr('disabled',true);
        $('#submit').css({opacity:0.5});
    }
});
```

I have 2 input, name & password, I need to bind paste, if user paste text & both input have text. than enable submit button, but my code is not working at moment

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: What means "is not working"? Which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: when i paste text into there 2 field, the submit button didn't enable

Comment: i already detect keyup for typing, but i need to make sure submit button also works when user try to paste instead typing

Comment: You should use prop() instead, depending which jq version you are using: `$('#submit').prop('disabled', true);` and `$('#submit').prop('disabled', false);`. But in your code, you are not checking for both input value, only one. You'd have better to use class instead of IDs. BTW, you could use oninput HTML5 event on modern browser to handle all cases as paste/keyup/cut etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#name,#password').on('paste', function(){
    var v = $('#name,#password').not(this).val();
    $('#submit').prop('disabled',!v).css({opacity:(v?1:0.5)});
});
```